# Android XML attribute references another xml attribute of the same type

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a custom View defined by this XML

*(part)*

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/LayoutVertWrapContent.SameWidth"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginRight="?betweenElementsPadding">

    ...
    some inner views
    ...

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout style="@style/LayoutVertWrapContent.SameWidth"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginRight="?betweenElementsPadding">

    ...
    some inner views
    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

For this view I have declared some attributes:

```
<declare-styleable name="TheView">
    ...
    <attr name="betweenElementsPadding" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

How can I declare this view in layout xml for an activity and pass **betweenElementsPadding** so that the `android:layout_marginRight="?betweenElementsPadding"` from the view's xml work?

```
<com.blablabla.TheView
        android:id="@+id/date" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        dct:betweenElementsPadding="@dimen/background_padding" />
```

The desired result is `android:layout_marginRight` for both LinearLayouts is set to **betweenElementsPadding**.

**UPDATE 1**

To prevent further misunderstanding, I want to have a uniformed way of changing **dct:betweenElementsPadding**, say

```
<com.blablabla.TheView
        android:id="@+id/date_1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        dct:betweenElementsPadding="3dp" />

<com.blablabla.TheView
        android:id="@+id/date_2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        dct:betweenElementsPadding="15dp" />

<com.blablabla.TheView
        android:id="@+id/date_3" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        dct:betweenElementsPadding="25dp" />
```

and in each of these cases I want **LinearLayout.layout_marginRight** to be set to exact value of **dct:betweenElementsPadding**, which is 3dp, 15dp and 25dp starting from the first.

**UPDATE 2**

Using workaround partially suggested by Joe.
In the styled constructor of the custom view I do this:

```
// set betweenElementsPadding
final int betweenElementsPadding = array.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.TheView_betweenElementsPadding, 0);
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_1)).getLayoutParams()).rightMargin = betweenElementsPadding;
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_2)).getLayoutParams()).rightMargin = betweenElementsPadding;
```

But I haven't found an answer to my original question of how to do the same with XML only.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
<style name="LayoutVertWrapContent.SameWidth" parent="someOtherStyleIfYouWant">
   <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/background_padding</item>
   <item name="android:layout_weight">2</item> <!-- if the same in all -->
</style>
```

without mixing attributes?

---

**Edit:**

This [link](http://kotikan.com/blog/posts/2012/09/android-attributes) may be helpful and also I think that using `xmlns:dct="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` will help with the recognition of `dct:betweenElementsPadding` in your xml.

```
<com.blablabla.TheView
        xmlns:dct="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/date" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        dct:betweenElementsPadding="@dimen/background_padding" />
```

Comment: Sorry. That doesn't help. I want to have a uniformed way of changing the attribute when I declare the view in layout XML. Look: `<com.blabla.TheView my:betweenElementsPadding="3dp" ... />.......<com.blabla.TheView my:betweenElementsPadding="15dp" ... />.....`, etc. and in each of these cases I only set **betweenElementsPadding** and I want **layout_marginRigh** for LinearLayouts of **TheView** to change to that value automatically. You're suggesting me to declare a **stlye** for each new separate value of **betweenElementsPadding**.

Comment: No in that way it may not be that useful... but if you only want to declare `layout_marginRight` I still cannot find any use of writing `dct:betweenElementsPadding=sth` instead of `layout_marginRight=sth`

Comment: Please, check updates section in the question above. In a few words, your approach won't work, because I want to declare several custom views with different `layout_marginRight` for each of them. Take into account that `layout_marginRight` is not in the activity's layout XML, but in the depth of custom view's XML, which I don't want to touch.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend dimens.xml. You can reference those to do things like app-wide left/right/top/bottom padding. You can also do things like use Views/ViewGroups (FrameLayout, for example) for padding

I think you also might be meaning to pass XML attributes to a custom view. On your view's constructor, there's the attrs parameter, plus commands to get those attributes like obtainStyledAttributes

Comment: The first part of your suggestion I don't understand.

Comment: As for the second part, do you mean I could parse attrs parameters in my custom view's constructor and proxy those parameters off to the appropriate params of the underlying views? Something like: `final float p = attr.getDimension(R.dimen.TheView_betweenElementsPadding, 0); MyLinearLayout.getLayout().rightMargin = p;`? If you meant this, I have thought about that one as well, but I want to find a simple way of how to make an XML attribute to get the value of another XML attribute simply by editing XML and not touching code. I can't believe there is no way to do that.

Comment: Sorry. The first part was me thinking it was normal, non-custom views. In this case, you can create values in dimens.xml to take advantage of "change it in one spot, and the padding changes to all places where that dimens value is". Thanks for the clarification on the second post. I think I get what you mean now, like being able to do something like "valueOfXMLValue * 2". Yeah, as far as I know, that requires a bit of Java work

Comment: For #1: android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/somePadding" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/somePadding" would make those two values change just by modifying somePadding in dimens.xml

Comment: Yep, Joe, you got it right, something like "valueOfXMLAttribute * 2". It would be sweet just to make a reference, say `android:attribute="theOtherAttribute_reference"` and it just magically works.

Comment: As for #1, I thought about it yesterday and first came to the same result, but that didn't solve the problem at all. How would you go about the part which comes after **UPDATE** above in my question? Sorry, but your comment doesn't provide even a workaround as I first thought.

Comment: It's okay, and sorry I have been away due to being sick. You can call that more than once. Trust me, I would love to hear a better answer than mine!